# Hide status bar in MPMediaPickerController?

Tags: xcode, hide, statusbar

In my app I want to hide the status bar in the MPMediaPickerController. I have set the status bar hidden property in my plist and it makes no difference. Is there anyway to hide it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`-setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden%3awithAnimation%3a).

Comment: on the MPMediaPickerController itself or do you mean on the UIApplication as a whole?

Comment: yea that somewhat seemed to do it. I found out after some testing, when I modal view is presented, if a status bar is already on screen it will continue to show that status bar and not just slide over it. So what I did was hide the status bar before I showed the MPMediaPickerController and then show it after I dismissed it. Thanks for your help and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass MPMediaPickerController and add:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}
```